# Macro to convert an indented hierarchy to a database format

Tags: performance, vba, excel, tree

Our business intelligence suite outputs data as an indented hierarchy, as below:

```
Level 1            1000
   Level 2a        600
      Level 3a     500
      Level 3b     100
   Level 2b        400
      Level 3c     400
```

I've written a macro that converts this into a 'database' format, where only rows with the base (most granular) level are preserved, and the parents are listed to the left as below (this way the # column is summable):

```
   1         2          3         #
Level 1   Level 2a   Level 3a    500
Level 1   Level 2a   Level 3b    100
Level 1   Level 2b   Level 3c    400
```

The problem I've been running into is that it takes 5-10 minutes to process a file with ~8000 rows. Although my code works, I'm convinced there's a faster way. See below for my code:

```
Sub Database()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS      As Worksheet
Dim SR      As Range
Dim Rows    As Integer
Dim Indent  As Integer
Dim TR      As Integer
Dim BR      As Integer

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'StartCell is a function that returns the address of the first cell in the hierarchy
Set SR = WS.Range(StartCell())
Rows = SR.End(xlDown).Row - SR.Row
BR = SR.End(xlDown).Row
TR = SR.Row

'Insert 4 columns & add headers (Level 1, Level 2, etc.)
For x = 0 To 3
    SR.EntireColumn.Insert
    SR.Offset(-1, -1) = "Level " & x + 3
Next x

x = 0
q = 0

'The main code
Do While x < Rows + 1
    'Identifies a row with base-level indentation & sets indent value to this level
    If Left(SR.Offset(x, 0), 5) = "P_PC7" Then
        Indent = SR.Offset(x, 0).IndentLevel
    End If
    i = 0
    'Loop while the indentation level is greater than one
    Do While Indent > 1
        'Move upwards and check whether indentation of new cell is one less than initial cell
        If SR.Offset(x - i, 0).IndentLevel = Indent - 1 Then
            'If so, this cell is the parent of the initial cell - copy it into the appropriate spot to the left of the base level cell
            SR.Offset(x - i, 0).Copy SR.Offset(x, -1 * (6 - Indent))
            'Set new indent level - the next loop will now look for the parent of the new cell
            Indent = SR.Offset(x - i, 0).IndentLevel
        'If indent level is not one less than initial cell, continue moving upward
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    x = x + 1
Loop

'Remove all rows that are not base-level
For q = BR To TR Step -1
    If WS.Cells(q, 6).IndentLevel <> 5 Then
       WS.Cells(q, 6).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next q

WS.UsedRange.IndentLevel = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks very much to JNevill for his solution - it is indeed significantly faster than my original code. I had to make some changes to accommodate more than one # column, as well as headers to the left of the indented hierarchy column i.e.:

```
Region        Base Level        Account 1     Account 2    

 USA         Level 1               500           800
 USA             Level 2a          300           400
 USA             Level 2b          200           400
```

Here is my new code based on JNevill's framework:

```
Sub HierarchyConvert()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim WS                      As Worksheet
Dim SR                      As Range
Dim LastRow                 As Long
Dim rngReadCell             As Range
Dim rngWriteRow             As Range
Dim Indent                  As Integer
Dim LastIndent              As Integer
Dim MaxIndent               As Integer
Dim ValueArray(0 To 19)     As Variant

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set SR = WS.Range(StartCell())
LastRow = SR.End(xlDown).Row
MaxIndent = 5

Set rngWriteRow = WS.Rows(SR.Row)

For x = 0 To 4
    SR.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    SR.Offset(-1, 1) = "Level " & 7 - x
Next x

SR.Offset(-1, 0) = "Level 2"
SR.Offset(-1, 5) = "PC"

For Each rngReadCell In WS.Range(SR.Address & ":B" & LastRow)
    Indent = rngReadCell.IndentLevel
    If Indent <= LastIndent And LastIndent <> 0 Then
        Set rngWriteRow = rngWriteRow.Offset(1)
        For i = 1 To Indent
            rngWriteRow.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rngWriteRow.Cells(1, i + 1).Offset(-1).Value
        Next i
    End If
    rngWriteRow.Cells(Indent + 2).Value = Trim(rngReadCell.Value)
    If Indent = MaxIndent Then
        'Copies leftmost header from base-level row to top left of write-row
        rngWriteRow.Cells(1) = rngReadCell.Offset(, -1).Value
        'Copies data to right of base-level row to the write-row
        For Z = 0 To 19
            ValueArray(Z) = rngReadCell.Offset(, Z + 6).Value
        Next Z
        For M = 0 To 19
            rngWriteRow.Cells(Indent + M + 3).Value = ValueArray(M)
        Next M
    End If
    LastIndent = Indent
Next rngReadCell

Range("A" & SR.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1 & ":Z" & LastRow + 1).ClearContents
WS.UsedRange.IndentLevel = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing your code first, there are several things you can do to make your code more consistent.

1. Always use `Option Explicit`. Please.
2. When you're looking at performance, you can do more than just disable `ScreenUpdating`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636805/4717755) for my usual solution if you feel you still need it.
3. Typical professional developers will use start variable names with lower case letters. Functions/Subs will start with upper case. CamelCaseVariableOrSubNames is also most common.
4. Your "main code" loop uses `Rows`, which implies the rows on the active worksheet. "Implying" which rows you're referencing will get you into loads of trouble. Always declare variables to specifically reference which worksheet or range that you're using and it's easier to keep it straight.

As with many of the performance questions in Code Review, your need for speed will be solved with a memory-based array. But one of the stumbling blocks you have is detecting the indent level for each of the rows in your source data. My quick solution is to create a "helper column" of data next to your source that uses a simple User Defined Function (UDF) to identify the indent level. The UDF is a single line:

```
Public Function GetIndent(ByRef target As Range) As Long
    '--- UDF to return the numeric indent level of the target cell
    '    handles the multi-cell case and will return the indent
    '    level of ONLY the top left cell of the range
    GetIndent = target.Resize(1, 1).IndentLevel
End Function
```

Using this function in the first column to the right of your data (`=GetIndent(A1)`) now turns my source data into this:

[image]

I had to do this because if I pull your original source data into an array, the array loses the indent level information. Otherwise, I'd have to continually refer back to the worksheet which is taking the bulk of your processing time.

**A quick side note** on how I am defining and accessing columns of data in my code. (I deeply regret I've lost track of which user on SO/CR I lifted this tip from. Whoever you are, mad props!) I find that much of my column-based data can change "shape" over a period of development and use. Columns can be added or deleted or switched in order. Hard-coding the column number in code then becomes problematic and forces lots of code changes to keep up. For the longest time I defined a set of `Const` declarations to keep track of column numbers, such as

```
Const COL_FIRST_NAME As Long = 1
Const COL_LAST_NAME As Long = 2
Const COL_ADDRESS As Long = 3
```

And this works just fine, but the names get tedious and it's easy to lose track of which constant to use for which range of data. So from one of the many things I've learned here, I now create an `Enum` to define column indexes that can more specifically be tied to a set of data. In the course of your solution, I have created

```
'--- convenience declarations for accessing data columns
Private Enum SrcColumns
    ID = 1
    Number = 2
    Indent = 3
End Enum

Private Enum DstColumns
    L1 = 1
    L2 = 2
    L3 = 3
    Number = 4
End Enum
```

You'll see how they are used below.

First get your data into your memory-based array:

```
Dim srcWS As Worksheet
Dim dstWS As Worksheet
Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dstWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'--- get our source data into an array
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim srcData As Variant
Set srcRange = srcWS.UsedRange
srcData = srcRange
```

We have to next figure out how many rows we'll need in our resulting database. This turns out to be straightforward by counting the number of times the maximum indent level appears in the data. In this case, the max indent level is 2. So:

```
Const MAX_LEVEL = 2
Dim i As Long
Dim maxDBRows As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)
    If srcData(i, SrcColumns.Indent) = MAX_LEVEL Then
        maxDBRows = maxDBRows + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Optionally (ideally), you can dynamically determine the maximum indent level instead of creating a `Const`. You could use a `WorksheetFunction` to accomplish the same thing if you'd prefer.

In order to create your database, I'm making a strict assumption that you will always encounter previous indent levels before reaching the maximum indent. This means that inside my loop I can capture all the level labels up to the maximum level and keep them. So creating the database now becomes a simple loop:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)
    Select Case srcData(i, SrcColumns.Indent)
        Case 0
            level1 = srcData(i, SrcColumns.ID)
        Case 1
            level2 = srcData(i, SrcColumns.ID)
        Case 2
            level3 = srcData(i, SrcColumns.ID)
            dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.L1) = level1
            dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.L2) = level2
            dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.L3) = level3
            dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.Number) = srcData(i, SrcColumns.Number)
            newDBRow = newDBRow + 1
    End Select
Next i
```

And finally, it's a quick copy to get the database array out to the destination:

```
Dim dstRange As Range
Set dstRange = dstWS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dstData, 1), UBound(dstData, 2))
dstRange = dstData
```

This runs very fast. Here's the entire module:

```
Option Explicit

'--- convenience declarations for accessing data columns
Private Enum SrcColumns
    ID = 1
    Number = 2
    Indent = 3
End Enum

Private Enum DstColumns
    L1 = 1
    L2 = 2
    L3 = 3
    Number = 4
End Enum

Public Function GetIndent(ByRef target As Range) As Long
    '--- UDF to return the numeric indent level of the target cell
    GetIndent = target.IndentLevel
End Function

Sub ConvertToDatabase()
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dstWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    '--- get our source data into an array
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim srcData As Variant
    Set srcRange = srcWS.UsedRange
    srcData = srcRange

    '--- we can determine how many rows in the destination database
    '    by getting a count of the highest indent level in the array
    Const MAX_LEVEL = 2
    Dim i As Long
    Dim maxDBRows As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)
        If srcData(i, SrcColumns.Indent) = MAX_LEVEL Then
            maxDBRows = maxDBRows + 1
        End If
    Next i

    '--- establish an empty database
    Dim dstData() As Variant
    ReDim dstData(1 To maxDBRows, 1 To 4)

    '--- load up the database
    Dim level1 As String
    Dim level2 As String
    Dim level3 As String
    Dim newDBRow As Long
    newDBRow = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)
        Select Case srcData(i, SrcColumns.Indent)
            Case 0
                level1 = srcData(i, SrcColumns.ID)
            Case 1
                level2 = srcData(i, SrcColumns.ID)
            Case 2
                level3 = srcData(i, SrcColumns.ID)
                dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.L1) = level1
                dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.L2) = level2
                dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.L3) = level3
                dstData(newDBRow, DstColumns.Number) = srcData(i, SrcColumns.Number)
                newDBRow = newDBRow + 1
        End Select
    Next i

    '--- finally copy the array out to the destination
    Dim dstRange As Range
    Set dstRange = dstWS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dstData, 1), UBound(dstData, 2))
    dstRange = dstData

End Sub
```

Comment: Named Ranges can also be used to stabilise code instead of fixed column numbers. I am working on a code base at the moment where I am using "magic numbers" similar to your constants (e.g. `COL_SOMETHING1_SOMETHING2`) but converting between column letter and column number when fixing the template is tedious. In the process of changing to named columns which means that the code base would never change again (*). _(*) for various definitions of "never"_

Comment: With your `IndentLevel` UDF: This works fine on an single cell, but can fail if multiple cells are passed. There was once an MSDN article that explained this but the new MSDN format is a lot blander and doesn't contain this useful in-depth information anymore.

Comment: You make a good point about multiple cells being passed to the UDF. I've modified the code to handle that case -- simplistically assuming that the indent level of the first cell (upper left) of the range will be returned.